# Nearest neighbour / spatial join with attribute condition

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, proximity

I have 2 point format datasets I wish to schematically join (manholes & gullies).  I am content that I can join them by nearest proximity alone using e.g. NNJoin plugin.

What I would like to do is add a further condition whereby the join is established by working out the nearest node conditional on that node having an elevation attribute equal to or less than the elevation attribute of the gully record, i.e. if nearest manhole is higher than the gully, then go to next nearest, etc, until a solution is found.

Is this possible using the build in tools in QGIS?

Comment: Can you use a spatial db? I think it's not possible using only qgis.

Comment: SQL spatial is the way to go, either SpatialLite or PostGIS...